# Extracting information from a text file using Python

Tags: python, csv, file, extract

I have the below text file with information that looks like this:

```
# found importantstuffhere
found request could not find identifier. Please check the name and try again.

I also have line that look like this:

# found importantstuffhere
finding (identifier here) with blah blah blah.
```

I want to write a python code that will go throw the the text file and extract

A. the first example is when the search failed, so I want to extract the 'importantstuffhere'
and the phrase 'found request could not find identifier'.

B. when it worked, as shown in second line, I want to extract 'importantstuffhere' and the phrase 'finding (identifier here)'

Is this possible with python and if so how?

Bonus point:

can I have the extracted values be placed in columns in a csv or excel file. such as

column A                       column B

importantstuffhere - and then for column B it would say either it found request could not find identifier or it would say finding (identifier here).

Thank you for your time!

Note: the # in the text file are part of the text file, I did not write them here just for clarification.

Essentially, extract the values needed, add them to a list so that I can later make them columns in a dataframe. perhaps list one has importantstuffhere and list 2 has the results

Comment: Should be possible in Python. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: Thank! I will share what I have, the issue is that I saw that for instances like this people used RegEx and I am not familiar with that at all.

Comment: Regex would be the best solution. To play around with them there is e. g. http://regex101.com (set to Python flavor).

Comment: please explain what you mean by extract. do you want to add the lines that match the phrase "found request could not find identifier" to a list?

Comment: I don't mind solving it if I knew what you want

Comment: Cody, yes that would be perfect! sorry

Comment: my apologies that isnt a list. give me 2 minutes

Comment: gonna try to write to csv this could take a few minutes

Comment: Are you trying to find the next line right after the script reads 'importantstuffhere'?

Comment: it isn't clear what you want in the csv and why you want that line. do you want to read ALL lines of a text file and put each line as a column in csv?

Comment: Ok. I want column A to have the first line # found importantstuffhere (just the importantstuff) each time that line is mentioned and then next to it in column B is the results of each find. so it would like this: colA =importantstuff1, colB= found request could not find identifier..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

script.py:

```
f = open('sampletext.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

important_stuff = []

{'line_number': None, 'line_text': ''}

for line_number, text in enumerate(lines):
    if text.find('found request could not find identifier') != -1:
        important_stuff.append({'line_number': line_number, 'line_text': text})

print(important_stuff)
```

The following will read a file, gather the lines into one string, and write them to a csv separated by commas:

```
f = open('sampletext.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

text_seperated_by_comma = ", ".join(lines)
text_without_line_breaks = text_seperated_by_comma.strip('\n')

with open('fileName.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    f = csv_file.write(text_without_line_breaks)
```

To check for a string then write the next line to csv file I have this:

```
f = open('sampletext.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

csv_lines_to_write = []

SEARCH_TEXT = 'importantstuffhere'

for line_number, text in enumerate(lines):
    if text.find(SEARCH_TEXT) != -1:
        next_line_index = line_number + 1
        next_line_text = lines[next_line_index]
        assert type(SEARCH_TEXT) is str
        assert type(next_line_text) is str
        csv_line_to_write = SEARCH_TEXT, + ', ' + lines[next_line_index]
        csv_lines_to_write.append(csv_line_to_write)

with open('fileName.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_lines_to_write:
        csv_file.write(text_without_line_breaks)
```

I'm getting error

```
csv_line_to_write = SEARCH_TEXT, + ', ' + lines[next_line_index]
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readlines.asp

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/python-check-if-string-contains-substring/

Comment: Cody, Thank you, I am going to go ahead and understand this and apply it and see if it works!